# How to read something readable from CSV file?

Tags: java, file, maven, csv, opencsv

I've got these code lines to read from a CSV file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file.csv"));
    List myEntries = reader.readAll();
    System.out.println(myEntries);
}
```

But what it returns to me is:

```
[[Ljava.lang.String;@6bc7c054, [Ljava.lang.String;@232204a1, etc.
```

My CSV file contains columns and rows (just like an Excel file). I have `name`, `society`, `import`, ...

How do I read exactly what's inside the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't use raw types: `List<String[]> myEntries`.

Secondly, what you are seeing there is the somewhat useless result of converting each list element - a `String[]` - to a `String`. You almost never want to call `toString()` on an array, whether implicitly or explicitly.

Instead, iterate through the list, using `Arrays.toString()` to print each element "usefully":

```
for (String[] row : myEntries) {
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java 8 version:

```
myEntries.forEach( stringArray -> System.out.println( Arrays.toString( stringArray ) ) );
```

Or if newlines aren't necessary:

```
System.out.println( Arrays.deepToString( myEntries.toArray() ) );
```

Comment: Or `myEntries.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);`